# ssl + nginx + apache + php: links are still displayed as http, not https

Tags: apache, ssl, nginx, vbulletin

I am using VBulletin Suite 4.1.4., which is written using PHP and nginx+apache setup (nginx as the front end server and Apache as the back-end server). This is a pretty standard "nginx+apache" configuration with nginx working on port 80 and apache on port 8080. I tried to enable https support and ran into the following problem.

As I read on the web, when one uses "nginx+apache" and wants to have https, he should configure ssl only for nginx server. So, I added required lines into nginx vhost configuration

```
    listen      443;
    server_name myserver.org;

    ssl         on;
    ssl_certificate     /tmp/myserver.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /tmp/myserver.key;
```

When I type https://.... the vBulletin forum opens in secure connection and the lock in the right bottom corner of the browser confirms it, so it looks like my settings work. At least to some extent.

But when I bring the mouse over links on the page, these links are showed as http links, not https. So, if I want to stay in secure connection, I can of course add the letter "s" manually each time I open a new page, but normally when you open forum as https://... all displayed links should automatically change to https.

Any ideas why this does not happen?

Even the answer where the problem lies - (a) in nginx configuration, or (b) in apache configuration or (c) in vbulletin configuration would help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Any ideas why this does not happen?` because your apache knows nothing about the type of connection used to connect to the nginx. Probably VBulletin generates the links with the same type of connection that is used during the connection between nginx and apache.

Comment: Your question is not related to programming and should be asked elsewhere, supposedly on http://ServerFault.com/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that vBulletin running on apache detects the HTTP protocol, not HTTPS. But, you can change vbulletin settings in the admin panel in the following way:

**Forum URL** to '**https**://your-site.name'

**Always use Forum URL as Base Path** to 'yes'

Comment: Does this mean that even people connecting via http will be forced to https protocol?

Comment: Yes, It does. Because vBulletin can't handle this situtation properly.